# Display data returned by function in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is the one thing that I am trying absolutely first time. I have made few websites in PHP and MySQL as DB but never used functions to get data from database.

But here is the thing that I am trying all new now as now I want to achieve `reusability` for a bog project. I wanted to get the order details from DB (i.e. `MySQL`) through `PHP Function`. I am bit confused that how to print values returned by a PHP function.

Function wrote by me is as below:

```
function _orderdetails(){
    $sql = "Select * from orders WHERE 1";
    $result = DB::instance()->prepare($sql)->execute()->fetchAll();
    return $result;
}
```

Please let me know how i can print these values and value returned by above function is an array.

I tried by calling function directly through print_r(_orderdetails());

Please let me know:

1. Efficient way of iterating through this function to Print Values.
2. Is there any other approach that can be better worked upon?

Comment: "Efficient way of iterating through this function to Print Values." - just create a basic loop: `foreach($result as $row){output row}`

Comment: "Is there any other approach that can be better worked upon?" - how many times do you call this function?

Comment: I knw this way of iterating @user4035.... But i want it through a function... I have no idea as of yet that how many times i need to call this.. Please tell me proper solution

Comment: "But i want it through a function" - you can't iterate through a function. Why do you need this? Sorry, your question is unclear. Can you prepare a minimal working example with sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot chain fetchAll() to execute() like this.

Besides, for a query that takes no parameters, there is no point in using execute(). So change your function like this

```
function _orderdetails(){
    $sql = "Select * from orders WHERE 1";
    return DB::instance()->query($sql)->fetchAll();
}
```

and so you'll be able to iterate results the most natural way

```
foreach (_orderdetails() as $order) {
    echo $order['id'] . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In your PHP code that will call this function use the following

```
print_r(_orderdetails()); 
//to get all the result set... I mean all the values coming from this function.
```

You can also use the function and use -> after the function call, then put the variable name as follows:

```
To iterate through the values of this function:
$value_arr = _orderdetails();
foreach ($valur_arr as $value) {
    echo $value . '<br />';
}
```

This way you will echo 1 column from the database table you are using.

Comment: Can i not write a differrnt function that iterates through result and print values then bt show me implementation

Comment: and with ur solution .. m getting `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: You can replace $order_details->db_column_name_in_orders_table with $order_details['db_column_name_in_orders_table'];

Answer (score -2):

You can also use `->fetch();`

Instead of `->fetchAll();`

There some other functions that also work as a worker to iterate through the next row in the table.

You can check PDO for more functions at:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php